# Spring Data MongoDB failed with "in" query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using spring-data-mongodb 1.8.0; MongoDB 3.0.6; mongo-java-driver 3.1.0;spring-framework.version 4.0.3.

What I want is to query a list of `user` with certain phone numbers.
example for user: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5625e5c32e1ca013a03f0d1b"), "phone" : "12345535"}`

In Mongo Shell `db.user.find({phone: { $in: [ "12345535", "123535"]}})` works fine. But in Spring I failed. Java Class User(with getters/setters omitted):

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    String id;
    String phone;
}
```

What I tried is:

```
Query q = new Query(Criteria.where("phone").in("12345535","123535"));
mongoTemplate.find(q, User.class);
```

It comes to error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException.detectPotentialMatches(PropertyReferenceException.java:134)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException.<init>(PropertyReferenceException.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.getPath(QueryMapper.java:837)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.<init>(QueryMapper.java:729)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.with(QueryMapper.java:740)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.with(QueryMapper.java:686)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedKeyword(QueryMapper.java:258)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObjectForField(QueryMapper.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:123)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1700)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1690)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:593)
    at com.example.TestMongo.main(TestMongo.java:30)
```

But with changing field *phone* to *id*, same code works fine.

```
Query q = new Query(Criteria.where("id").in("5625e5c32e1ca013a03f0d1b","f0d1e"));
mongoTemplate.find(q, User.class);
```

With debugging, I find that it even didn't go to the request phase, error occurred in the *query-building* phase. It seems `$in` cannot be processed by `PropertyPath.create`, while in the `id` case, it can.

How can I fix this? I am a newbie and searched a lot but got no luck.Can you please help me out. Every answer is appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As indicated in the [announcement blog](https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/01/spring-data-release-train-gosling-goes-ga) and the [release train wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Gosling), Spring Data MongoDB 1.8 requires Spring 4.1, ideally 4.1.8 which includes an important security fix.

Comment: Spring 4.1.5 still has the same problem with MongoDB 1.8.1, BUT switching to Spring 4.1.8 works for me. (Spring 4.1.8.RELEASE + Spring MongoDB 1.8.1)

Comment: Thank you, switching Spring to 4.2.3.RELEASE and Spring Data MongoDB to 1.8.1.RELEASE works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue have appeared on me while using Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE and Spring MongoDB 1.6.1

Switching to Spring mongoDB 1.8.1 solves the issue.

(Meant as a comment to @OliverGierke's answer, but couldn't do it, due to low reputation level.)

Comment: If you don't have enough reputation to comment, wait until you do. For more information, I suggest you read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/349538

Comment: Thanks for the info!